# Git in PHPstorm: Unstage files from Git (remove uncommited files from stage)

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm

In PHPStorm's Git interface it's easy to stage files and folders, with the "+Add" option in the "Git >" submenu of the right click context menu. But, how do I remove them from stage?

Comment: It'd be nice if the person downvoting my question would explain the reason (i.e: Is it a duplicate of another question?)

Comment: Question upvotes have +5 and downvotes have -2. I upvoted and now you have +3 :) have a good day. But the explanation is about lack of research before asking quesitions

Comment: [Trial and Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_and_error), is one of so many known [Problem-solving strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_solving#Problem-solving_strategies).  By [research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research) I mean deep googling and reading [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/documentation). Have fun

Comment: But my question was about doing it from PHPStorm, NOT from console. Also, if everyone answered every question in StackOverflow with a "Google it" answer, this site would have no point. Also, often Google returns results from StackOverflow when looking up things. If every answer here was "Google it", it'd be a waste of time for everyone googling as well because they'd only find a useless "Google it" answer while actually googling ;-). And, as I said, Git documentation is useful for console, not for my question, which was pertaining a particular GUI (PHPStorm).

Comment: Did you check `PHP Storm > Preferences > Version Control > Ignored Files`?

Comment: Yes, I already scoured the Preferences window ;), but that "Ignored files" section adds files to the ".gitignore" file, which is different from just removing an added file.

Comment: This question in not precise. What exactly is "removing"? Do you mean already committed files or staged files? Or maybe already pushed files?

Comment: Well, you are right that "remove" is a bit vague. Thanks for the edit. Yes, I actually meant "unstage". But since PHPStorm option to "stage" a file is called "Add" I used the antonym word to that, which is "remove".

Comment: "lack of research", "google it", "learn how to problem-solve"

I googled this question and landed here... does that count?

Comment: See? That's what I was talking about! ;-)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've found an easy (but not obvious) way to remove files from Git in PHPStorm (or any other IntelliJ based IDE) when they still haven't been committed (for example, you "add"/stage some files which will finally not be used).

You just have to right click the file and select "Git > Rollback" ("Git > Revert" in older versions). Since it's still not commited, "rolling back"/"reverting" will actually "remove"/unstage the file from Git.

You even have the option to physically remove the file by checking the "Delete local copies of added files" option, or just leave it as it is after removing it from Git by leaving that option unchecked (in that case the file will be shown in red as if it still hadn't been added).

Comment: this works, it's weird that I need to revert, but it kind of makes sense I guess

Answer (score 7):

You have no choice but to use console/terminal for that. `git rm -–cached <file>` if I'm not mistaken.

They do not plan to implement such rarely used functionality (unless I've missed the newer ticket): http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107359

Comment: Thank you! I don't get why they think this that it's reasonable not to have a Remove feature. Even if removing files from VCS is a lot less frequent than adding them, it would still be useful and it's not like implementing that would take weeks of work.

Comment: I think that should be `--cached` not `-cached`

Comment: I just submitted an edit correction to this answer rabout the `--cached` issue @Pmpr mentioned since I didn't see until I'd already did copy & paste and got an error.

Answer (score 0):

To unstage file from phpstorm you ave to right click on file and rollback so the file will be inside unversioned files

Comment: Your solution was already mentioned here in an answer posted 5 years before you wrote this answer, but thanks anyway for your contribution.